# Make the shape have the same look and feel in different android device using opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using opengl in my android application, I tried to draw some polylines, however I found that the lines have different sizes(from the user's perspective) because of the different dpi.

For example I set the line width 6px.

Then in a high dpi device, the line may look like less than that of in a lower dpi device.

I try to multiple the size with dpi, but it does not work, and also I am afraid the size may out of the limit of opengl line width .

Any idea to fix this?